# Can signals pass through a single wire in both directions simultaneously?

Tags: circuit-analysis, signal-theory

Can electric signals pass through a single wire in both directions simultaneously?

To be clear, I mean signals that are not somehow modulated to avoid interference. I also mean a wire, and not a waveguide such as a coaxial cable.

Perhaps a cleverly designed circuit at each end could 'cancel out' the outgoing signal (e.g. using a differential amplifier) from the combined input and output signals, so that only the incoming signal is received.

Comment: You are not allowing modulation and then suggesting methods that imply modulation. Two people talking to each other at the same time: What do you think they are doing with their voices? They are modulating their voices to speak.

Comment: @DKNguyen Sorry I wasn't clear. I mean both signals are in the same (or at least overlapping) band of frequencies. I just wanted to avoid possibly trivial cases like: 1 signal is AM at 1KHz, the other signal is AM at 100kHz.

Comment: I think you just subtract your incoming signal from your outgoing signal. You also need rectifying inputs and outputs.

Comment: You just described a directional coupler!

Comment: A single wire has no current return path hence your question appears to be significantly flawed. You need to be precise about what you mean.

Comment: Gigabit Ethernet does this.

Comment: @Andy aka Assume the circuit one each end is connected to ground/earth

Answer (score 6):

Conventional telephone service wiring sends signals in both directions simultaneously using a 'hybrid'.

[Wikipedia - Telephone Hybrid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_hybrid)
[image]

Comment: the OP said `single wire`

Comment: @jsotola - did you heard about industry standard "1-Wire Protocol"? 1 wire for data + 1 wire for GND.

Comment: a singe wire telephone has a simpler circuit but you get the same result.

Comment: @jsotola - I interpreted the OP's question as being over a "single circuit", i.e. there is also a return connection.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Look up simultaneous bidirectional links for more information.
You are correct in that you need an "echo" cancellation circuit that cancels out the outgoing signal at one end so (ideally) only the receiving signal is seen.

It is very difficult to this in continuous time, in sampled time only the sampled points need to be subtracted which makes it much more straightforward (although still hard).

There will be a transmitter and also another circuit that replicates the what the transmitted signal looks like (the echo cancellation circuit). Since the transmitter is affected by the channel the echo cancellation circuit will need to take that in account. Below is a very basic block diagram of a typical simultaneous bidirectional link.

The output of the "Slicer" is the final signal.

[image: Bidirectional IO link]